# Should tags 'anime' and 'animation' be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

Current descriptions:
'anime' tag: "Most likely referring to Japanese style of animation and English term for animated series originating in Japan."

'animation' tag: "Movies or shows that consist entirely of either hand drawn or computer drawn/generated content"

I see anime as being a subset of animation and anime can be drawn in a wide variety of ways, some of which are very similar to non-Japanese styles.  There are also many non-Japanese(more common in other Asian countries) animated works that are similar in style to Japanese 'anime'.

They are (as of writing) our 27th and 28th most active tags.  I just don't think there's enough difference between the 2 to justify an extra tag, and I propose making 'anime' a synonym for 'animation', with 'animation' being the master.

Comment: Your suggestion sounds both reasonable and not quite right all at the same time.  Animation is as you say a very generic term. Anime has a much more specific genre meaning to my ears. However as I am not an expert in anime, I'm going to leave it for others to weigh in on this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I disagree.

Anime itself is a sub-genre of Animation as a whole.  That is correct.

But at the same time, it implies a specific set of works that is very distinguishable from regular animation.

When thinking about regular animation, I tend to think of Cartoon Network and Nickelodeon (US cartoon broadcasting channels, for those outside the States).

When talking about Anime, I assume works that originate in Japan, or have been influenced by that style.

It is not as if we are arguing (referring to music genre's here) if alternative-new-wave metal should be merged with heavy alternative rocking out metal.

Comment: Anime is also a very large subset.

Comment: Coincidentally, anime.SE just went into private beta.